# How edit my function and add out parameters array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am have func Json decode, how i modernize my function and add out parameters Array type my "model" data?

I need add all decode data  "let model" in another global array.
Example:

```
let myArray = [Any]()
```

in the function i think add

```
myArray.append(model.Welcome)
```

my code for decode JSON:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo
}

struct Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String
}

struct Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String
}


func userApiJsonCodableClass () {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }

        do {
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let model = try decoder.decode([Welcome].self, from:
                dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data
            print("---------CodableClass---------")
            print(model[0].website) //Output - 1221
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain  more what actually you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change at first here: `var myArray = [Welcome]()`. Second, collect your items directly to an array: `myArray = try decoder.decode([Welcome].self, from: dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data`.

Dont forget to clear an array in case of error parsing.

```
var myArray = [Welcome]()

struct Welcome: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo
}

struct Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String
}

struct Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String
}


    func userApiJsonCodableClass () {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else {return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data,
                error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                    return }

            do {
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()


                myArray = try decoder.decode([Welcome].self, from:
                    dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data



                print("---------CodableClass---------")
                print(myArray.first?.website) //Output - 1221
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
                myArray = []
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Simple way, you can directly add you parsed array into your global array `"myArray"` and use `var` for `myArray` like:

`var myArray = [Welcome]()`

```
myArray = try decoder.decode([Welcome].self, from:
            dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data
```